# ¿Cómo recibir una lista desde un controlador de ASP.NET MVC a una petición AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc, controller

Mi petición Ajax es la siguiente:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "http://localhost:60096/Zona/getZonas",
        success: function (mensaje) {
            alert("Success");            
        },
        error: function (mensaje) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    })
```

Como se puede observar se llama al método getZonas del controlador Zona. Hasta ahí funciona bien. Este es el código del controlador

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult getZonas()
        {
            ControllerZona zona = new ControllerZona();
            List<DtoZona> colZonas = zona.ListAll().Cast<DtoZona>().ToList();
            return Json(colZonas);
        }
```

Por alguna razón esto no funciona. Directamente alerta el error. No sé si tengo que retornar algo diferente a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

El problema ya quedó resuelto. Como una zona contiene una colección de objetos cuadrilla, y una cuadrilla tiene un objeto zona, se produjo una referencia circular. Para evitarlo hay que crear objetos anónimos. Y es importante aclarar el comportamiento que habrá ante tal petición. Se resuelve de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult getZonas()
        {
            ControllerZona zona = new ControllerZona();
            List<DtoZona> colZonas = zona.ListAll().Cast<DtoZona>().ToList();
            var zonas = colZonas.Select(i => new { nombre = i.nombre, color = i.color, colPuntos = i.colPuntos }); // Si no se hace 
            return Json(zonas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```